# yolov5 model , adding metadata to the input images

Tags: metadata, yolov5, yolov8

I have images , and I have the metadata of the camera of the drone that take the images , I want to add this data to the input of the yolo model(yolov5,yolov8).can i add it to the input txt file? or give me some ideas ...

i search alot but this the only this that chagpt give me is to add this file

- dataset/

  - metadata.txt
  - image001.jpg
  - image001.txt
  - image002.jpg
  - image002.txt
    in this way , but I didn't see any one do it !!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics of Yolov5 and Yolov8, but to my knowledge these architectures only support image inputs and only differ in the way those images are processed. If you want to give additional information to the network that could help it to identify objects, you would need to create your own network architecture for this purpose.

However, you could use this hacky work-around:

Say you have two different drones (one flew over forests, one over the ocean) and you want to make life easier for the network (aka only suggest mammals for camera 1 and only fish for camera 2), you could extend each input image by a line of pixels with 1 for camera 1 and a line of pixels with 0 for camera 2 etc.

The network would learn that classes depend on this artificial lines and use this information... If you specify the meta data and how data depends on it, we might be able to provide you with more suitable ideas.

Comment: i want to detects and counts cows from drone images , I have a lot of information from the drone that I want to add  , i have specific problem that the model don't recognize black cows in dark ground.

Comment: I wonder what kind of meta information that might be that will help Yolo to find the cows?

Comment: Let's say data that I calculate like the distance from which the picture was taken.

Comment: But then you should use this information to scale the input images to all have the same "millimeters per pixel". You should use this information in preprocessing rather than as an input to the network. Also, Yolo is able to learn different scales out of the box (however, scaling with known factor makes it easier), as it uses different anchor boxes (at least in earlier versions).